# How to filter laptop/notebook users in Google Analytics Reports

Tags: google-analytics, report, filtering

I am trying to set the correct filters in Google Analytics under Audience>Technology in order to view only the users using a laptop/notebook. Is this possible in Google Analytics and if so, which filters do I have to use?

Thanks, 
Peter

Comment: Reporting question are generally OT (it is usually suggested that they should go to webmasters.stackexchange.com), but there is no specific "labtop"-dimension.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about usage of the Google Analytics website and is not programing related may be better suited for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you cant distinguish between desktop and notebooks in google analytics. Just Desktop (which includes laptops), Tablet, and Mobile.
[google support Acquisition Device](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123672?hl=en)